# ssh: connect to host IP port 22: Connection timed out in Azure

Tags: azure, ssh

I have ubuntu server hosted in Azure VM. Till yesterday I was able to login.

ssh name@xx.xx.xx.xx.xx
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection timed out

I went through the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-ssh-connection

still not able to login. any other way around.

I have reset the 2-3 times password and reset the configuration worked for me

> > But now I am facing a new challenge if 4 hours if my system go to idle(VM running no login to server) state with out login i need to reset the password and reset the configuration, is there any permanenet way to solve this.

Comment: When you check the NSG rules, do you check the network in your local? And do you check if the public IP address of the VM is right? The error message is the time-out, it means your VM cannot be reachable.

Comment: @CharlesXu, by doing the resetting the password it works. Today It also shows connection time out. So i have reset the password and reset the configuration again, Any idea why this is happening daily

Comment: You solved the problem by resetting the password. So you need to close this question and add another one for the reason why does it happen. It never happens to me. So I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's due to an enforced Azure Policy. If you connect via ssh using a RSA key, does it also happen?

Check this info about the password policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#password-policies-that-only-apply-to-cloud-user-accounts